# Recursion Working problem with dictionary

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I have a doubt on recursion. Please help to clarify my doubt.

I have a data structure to store a Binary Tree node:

```
 class Node:
        def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None):
            self.data = key
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
    # Recursive function to print left view of given binary tree
    def printLeftView(root,level=0,leveldic={}):
        if root==None:
            return
        print(root.data,leveldic)
        if level not in leveldic:
            leveldic[level]=root.data
            print(root.data)
        printLeftView(root.left,level+1,leveldic)
        printLeftView(root.right,level+1,leveldic)
    
"""
                      1
                    /    \
                   2       3
                  /      /    \
                4      5      6
                       \       
                        8

"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(1)
    root.left = Node(2)
    root.right = Node(3)
    root.left.right = Node(4)
    root.right.left = Node(5)
    root.right.right = Node(6)
    root.right.left.right = Node(8)
    printLeftView(root)
```

Output:

```
> ​1 {}
>     1
>     2 {0: 1}
>     2
>     4 {0: 1, 1: 2}
>     4
>     3 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4}
>     5 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4}
>     8 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4}
>     8
>     6 {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 8}
```

Doubt:

Why doesn't the dictionary go back to its orginal state after returning?

i.e.,  after print 4 dictionary is

{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4}

and since it return and when back to node 3, it should back to previous state while returning became

{0: 1, 1: 3}

this did not happen, the dictionary doesn't get the change and it is same as from the Node 4.

{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4}

What could be the reason?​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that dictionary argument isn't a copy of dictionary, but reference to it in memory, so when it should back to node 3, it is with old keys. You must make copy of it.

```
def printLeftView(root,level=0,oldic={}):
    if root==None:
        return

    leveldic={} #making new dict
    for i in oldic:
        leveldic[i]=oldic[i] #and copying it values, to work on copy
    
    leveldic[level]=root.data
    print(root.data)
    print(root.data,leveldic)

    printLeftView(root.left,level+1,leveldic)
    printLeftView(root.right,level+1,leveldic)
```

Comment: Hai,  Is this specific to python language or same in case of c++/Java etc:?

Comment: @PranavM it can happen in other languages too, but in C++ usually it's intended, because declaration of function will look something like that `void fun(datatype *variable)`, where ' * ' mean it's reference to variable. I'm not sure, but I think some datatypes from libraries may work like that by default.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not correct: it will produce the wrong output.

The original code is exactly as the algorithm is supposed to work: there is one dictionary that is shared by all recursive execution contexts, and it *should not* return to a previous state when coming back from a recursive call. If you try to "fix" this, you will actually break the algorithm, and the output will generally be wrong then.

Be aware that the dictionary object is not deep-copied when you pass it as argument to a function: the function will get the argument in a new variable, but it is still the same dictionary. Unless a new value is *assigned* to that variable, any *mutation* to this dictionary will be to that *single* dictionary instance.

There is however another problem with your code: the default parameter value `leveldic={}` is problematic. This assignment happens only once, which is a behaviour that is quite specific to Python. This means that if you make the call again from the main program, you will *still continue* with the dictionary object as it was after the last call.

You would need it to get reset if such a second call is made:

```
def printLeftView(root, level=0, leveldic=None):
    if leveldic is None:
        leveldic = {}
    if root is None:
        return
    if level not in leveldic:
        leveldic[level] = root.data
        print(root.data)
    printLeftView(root.left, level + 1, leveldic)
    printLeftView(root.right, level + 1, leveldic)
```

Comment: Hai, thanks for you explanation. As far i understand is, python use call by reference automatically in function call where as java and all not unless it specified. So what would be the option for reset the dictionary back to its orginal state after return. Make a deepcopy and use it in each call, pop() item after return?. Or any ither methods?

Comment: Why would you want this? As I explained, it would make this algorithm go wrong. If you have a case where it would actually be *needed* for an algorithm to work correctly, then please ask about that in a new question. But here it should stay like it is. The way arguments are passed is quite similar to Java actually. In Java, when you pass a hash map as argument, it is a reference -- no copy is made. Where it works differently is in C-like languages where you have `struct`.

Comment: I know that it get wrong. I doesnt care about algorithm now. only need to know the reason abd possible alternative for my requirement.

Comment: What is your requirement? I find it strange that you ask about an algorithm and don't care that the algorithm will break by the answer you want to hear. Strange indeed.

Comment: For any one else coming here: the accepted answer is not correct. That code will produce the wrong output.

Comment: My requirement is clearly specified and the accepted answer give more statisfication.